# Use regex to find and modify try-catch blocks

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have lots of code blocks like:

```
try
{
 ...
}
catch(Exception123 &e)
{
 ...
}
```

I want to replace them with something like this:

```
MY_MACRO(try
{
 ...
})
catch(Exception123 &e)
{
 ...
}
```

`Exception123` is key, only blocks catching that specific type should be identified. But the exception caught might not always be called `e` or exist at all. And the precise structure and formatting of the code-block isn't always the same... we might have `try {`.

Is it feasible to use regex in a Visual-Studio find-replace for this? I couldn't figure out how I would group/identify the main try block.

Comment: Do you have nested `try/catch` occurences? Also, this might sound familiar: what have you tried?

Comment: I don't - `MY_MACRO` is actually introducing them.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://regex101.com/r/gM5iC3) is supported in visual studio: `(?is)try\s*\{.*?\}(?=\s*catch\s*\(\s*exception123[^)]*\))`, but that's the basic idea...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Sorry, I havn't saw the second part of your question :

I think there is the regex you want for search :

```
(try[\r\n]+{[^\}]+[\r\n]+)(})([\r\n]+catch\(Exception123)
```

And in replacement field :

```
MY_MACRO($1$2)$3
```